# c++: cross interactions within dual hierarchy

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In a C++ application, I have two class hierarchies, one for `Worker`s and for `Stuff`. I want each sub-class of `Worker` to interact differently with each sub-class of `Stuff` through a `do_stuff` function. I'm not sure how to do that without systematically down-casting both the `worker` and `stuff` inside `do_stuff` and have specific treatments for each possibility.

Moving `do_stuff` to be a method for either `Worker` or `Stuff` and overriding in the sub-classes removes the need for one down-cast, but not the other.

Is there a specific good pratice to handle similar cases ?

Code structure is as below:

```
class Worker;
class Worker1 : public Worker;
class Worker2 : public Worker;

class Stuff;
class StuffA : public Stuff;
class StuffB : public Stuff;

void do_stuff(Worker worker, Stuff stuff);

int main() {
    vector<Worker*> worker_vec = whatever;
    vector<Stuff*> stuff_vec = whatever;

    for(Worker* worker : worker_vec) {
        for(Stuff* stuff: stuff_vec) {
            do_stuff(*worker, *stuff);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for visitor pattern - in general multiple dispatch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of an effort to implement, but at least possible:

```
class Worker1;
class Worker2;

class Stuff
{
public:
    virtual ~Stuff() { }
    virtual void doStuff(Worker1*) = 0;
    virtual void doStuff(Worker2*) = 0;
};

class Worker
{
public:
    virtual ~Worker() { }
    virtual void doStuff(Stuff* stuff) = 0;
};
class Worker1 : public Worker
{
    void doStuff(Stuff* stuff) override
    {
        stuff->doStuff(this);
    }
};

// another approach: CRTP; spares the work of having to rewrite
// the overridden function again and again...
template <typename T>
class Stuffer : public Worker
{
public:
    void doStuff(Stuff* stuff) override
    {
        stuff->doStuff(static_cast<T*>(this));
    }
};
class Worker2 : public Stuffer<Worker2>
{
};

class Worker2 : public Worker
{
    void doStuff(Stuff* stuff) override
    {
        stuff->doStuff(this);
    }
};

class StuffA : public Stuff
{
public:
    void doStuff(Worker1*) override
    {
        std::cout << "StuffA + Worker1\n";
    }
    void doStuff(Worker2*) override
    {
        std::cout << "StuffA + Worker2\n";
    }
};
class StuffB : public Stuff
{
public:
    void doStuff(Worker1*) override
    {
        std::cout << "StuffB + Worker1\n";
    }
    void doStuff(Worker2*) override
    {
        std::cout << "StuffB + Worker2\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Worker*> worker_vec = { new Worker1, new Worker2 };
    std::vector<Stuff*> stuff_vec = { new StuffA, new StuffB };

    for(Worker* worker : worker_vec)
    {
        for(Stuff* stuff: stuff_vec)
        {
            worker->doStuff(stuff);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All without explicit (`dynamic_`)casts...

For `Worker2` I did the implementation via the curiously recurring template pattern – re-introducing a cast, yes, but a `static_cast` which is for free at runtime so probably won't mind. It would relieve you from having to write the overridden function again and again...

Demo on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/scMrEE851).